# Dynamically loading in script tags fails on page refresh

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a web application in AngularJS, therefore we have a lot of script tags. For debugging purposes we want all of them loaded in individually, but we are also using a plain HTML page, so we don't have the luxury of ASP.net bundling etc.

For ease of use I was going to create a single JS file that loaded all our other files, so all our developers would only have to put a single file on the page and they could just update the master list the function reads from.

This works great on initial page load when I run my application, but when I refresh the page everything is totally whacked out.

I'm looking for a fix for this, or a better way to load in my scripts.

Javascript:

First define the scripts to be loaded in:

```
var scripts = {
    libs: [
        "jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js",
        "angularjs/angular.js",
        "kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.all.min.js",
        "d3/d3.js"
    ],
    modules: [
        "hiModule.js"
    ],
    common: [
        "Classes.js"
    ],
    components: [
        "contentArea/contentAreaCtrl.js",

        "kendoGrid/kendoGridDir.js",
        "kendoGrid/kendoGridCtrl.js",
        "kendoGrid/kendoGridSvc.js",

        "login/loginDir.js",
        "login/loginCtrl.js",

        "search/searchCtrl.js",
        "search/searchDir.js",

        "sidebar/sidebarDir.js"
    ],
    services: [
        "sessionTrackerSvc.js"
    ]

};
```

Then build the script URLs and add them to a fileQueue:

```
function buildScriptUrls() {
    var i;
    for (var key in scripts) {
        if (key) {
            var fileUrl;
            var arrayLength = scripts[key].length;
            for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
                if (key === "libs") {
                    fileUrl = "Scripts/libs/" + scripts[key][i];
                } else if (key !== "modules") {
                    fileUrl = "Scripts/SPEnterprisePortal/" + key + "/" + scripts[key][i];
                } else {
                    fileUrl = "Scripts/SPEnterprisePortal/" + scripts[key][i];
                }
                fileQueue.push(fileUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, create the scripts and append all of them to the page.

```
function appendChild() {
    if (counter > 0) {

        counter -= 1;
        var curFile = fileQueue[counter];
        var jsFile = document.createElement("script");
        jsFile.type = "text/javascript";
        jsFile.src = curFile;
        jsFile.onload = appendChild();
        jsFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == "complete") {
                appendChild();
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(jsFile);
    }
}
```

The actual execution happens in an IIFE at the bottom of the script:

```
var fileQueue = [];
buildScriptUrls();
var counter = fileQueue.length;
appendChild();
```

You'll notice that the function starts at the end of the list of scripts and works it's way backward. This is because of the nested nature of my function calls. All the scripts are created, but each the `appendChild()` function calls itself and doesn't append the script to the page until it's loaded. Because of this, the last script called gets added to the page first so the function needs to work backwards.

This is of my own invention so I'm certain there's a better way of doing it, but right now I'm just trying to figure out why it works fine on load, and then on page refresh it all breaks!

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of refresh breaks things? control+F5 = broke, but second time page works?

Comment: Looks like any refresh breaks it: Ctrl + F5, F5, Ctrl + R. But once again, initial launch from Visual Studio on debugging runs fine, and if I open it in a different browser when I am already debugging it also works fine.

Comment: Have you fired up a http watcher like fiddler? Maybe you're getting some 404s?

Comment: I did, but should have paid more attention. When the reload fails, it's because the browser is throwing a 304 for all the scripts.